# Collision detection in joint body

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x

I have created train.  It is combined(joint) rectangle, axle, wheel.  I want to detect collision rectangle with other body(star or fruit).

Any idea or suggestion should help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I gave this answer to another question recently.  I assume you are using box2d for the train parts.

If you are using box2d, then the collision detection is handled in the Box2d engine when it processes the world update.  This detects the collision between fixtures on the body, not the body itself.  So if your body is made of a group of fixtures, you can get detection down to a very small part of the body (and not just the bounding rectangles).

The simple answer is to derive a class from b2ContactListener and tell the b2World you want to use it.  The example from the manual looks like this:

```
class MyContactListener : public b2ContactListener 
{
public:
void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact) { /* handle begin event */ }
void EndContact(b2Contact* contact) { /* handle end event */ }
void PreSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2Manifold* oldManifold) { /* handle pre-solve event */ }
void PostSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2ContactImpulse* impulse)
{ /* handle post-solve event */ } 
};
```

You register it using b2World::SetContactListener(...) on an instance of your derived class.

HOWEVER, it is not quite as simple as that.  My experience is that for a single "collision" you get multiple calls to your class during the world update.  So if the collision destroys an object during the collision detection phase, you may have problems (dead pointers?) when the other events occur during the same detection cycle.

Below is a more complete solution.  In this, each "thing" in the world has a b2Body and the user tag points back to the root class (called Entity).  It accumulates a list of collisions and checks to see if each new event references a pair that was already seen, filtering out duplicates.  After the world update NotifyCollisions is called to send messages to the entities that a collision has occurred and they need to do something about it.

This is part of a larger code base; feel free to ask any questions if you need clarification because the code is not here.

```
class EntityContactListener : public ContactListener
{
private:
   GameWorld* _gameWorld;
   EntityContactListener() {}

   typedef struct 
   {
      Entity* entA;
      Entity* entB;
   } CONTACT_PAIR_T;

   vector<CONTACT_PAIR_T> _contactPairs;

public:
   virtual ~EntityContactListener() {}

   EntityContactListener(GameWorld* gameWorld) :
      _gameWorld(gameWorld)
   {
      _contactPairs.reserve(128);
   }

   void NotifyCollisions()
   {
      Message* msg;
      MessageManager& mm = GameManager::Instance().GetMessageMgr();

      for(uint32 idx = 0; idx < _contactPairs.size(); idx++)
      {
         Entity* entA = _contactPairs[idx].entA;
         Entity* entB = _contactPairs[idx].entB;

         //DebugLogCPP("Contact Notification %s<->%s",entA->ToString().c_str(),entB->ToString().c_str());

         msg = mm.CreateMessage();
         msg->Init(entA->GetID(), entB->GetID(), Message::MESSAGE_COLLISION);
         mm.EnqueueMessge(msg, 0);

         msg = mm.CreateMessage();
         msg->Init(entB->GetID(), entA->GetID(), Message::MESSAGE_COLLISION);
         mm.EnqueueMessge(msg, 0);         
      }
      _contactPairs.clear();
   }

   void PreSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2Manifold* oldManifold)
   {

   }

   // BEWARE:  You may get multiple calls for the same event.
   void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
   {
      Entity* entA = (Entity*)contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody()->GetUserData();
      Entity* entB = (Entity*)contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody()->GetUserData();
      //DebugLogCPP("Begin Contact %s->%s",entA->ToString().c_str(),entB->ToString().c_str());
      if(entA->GetGroupID() == entB->GetGroupID())
      {  // Can't collide if they are in the same group.
         return;
      }

      assert(entA != NULL);
      assert(entB != NULL);

      for(uint32 idx = 0; idx < _contactPairs.size(); idx++)
      {
         if(_contactPairs[idx].entA == entA && _contactPairs[idx].entB == entB)
            return;
         // Not sure if this is needed...
         if(_contactPairs[idx].entA == entB && _contactPairs[idx].entA == entB)
            return;
      }
      CONTACT_PAIR_T pair;
      pair.entA = entA;
      pair.entB = entB;
      _contactPairs.push_back(pair);
   }

   // BEWARE:  You may get multiple calls for the same event.
   void EndContact(b2Contact* contact)
   {
      /*
      Entity* entA = (Entity*)contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody()->GetUserData();
      Entity* entB = (Entity*)contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody()->GetUserData();
      DebugLogCPP("End Contact %s->%s",entA->ToString().c_str(),entB->ToString().c_str());
       */
   }
};
```

Was this helpful?

Comment: i have separated the rectangle portion and created contact listener for rectangle area.  After that i included the rectangle in train object.  It is working fine. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can set userdata for that rectangle body and your other body(star or fruit).
You have to also extend b2contactlistner(cocos2d-x). which have few method

`void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact) { /* handle begin event */ }
    void EndContact(b2Contact* contact) { /* handle end event */ }
    void PreSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2Manifold* oldManifold) { /* handle pre-solve      event */ }
   void PostSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2ContactImpulse* impulse)`

One of these method you get the body userdata and check if your train body userdat collide with other body userdat.

For example

```
void HelloWorld::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
    b2Body * bodyA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
    b2Body * bodyB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();
//  CCSprite sp1 = (CCSprite*)bodyA->GetUserData();
//  CCSprite sp2 = (CCSprite*)bodyB->GetUserData();
//  b2Body *b1 = (new Layerhero())->b1;
    CCLog("In the begincontact");

    if((bodyA == hero && bodyB == hero2))
{
    CCLog("In the begincontact1");
    boo = true;
}
else if ((bodyA == hero && bodyB == hero3))
{
    CCLog("In the begincontact2");
    boo = true;
}
```

}